# Problem on adressing nested relative directories in server

Tags: python, path

I want to run some image processing code on a Linux server.

The code is located in

```
/q/w/e/r/t
```

The images are located in

```
/abc/d/e/f/g # the images are in the g folder
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
path = "/abc/d/e/f"

new_path = os.path.join(path, 'g', '001.png')

img1= cv2.imread(new_path)
```

However, this is the error I'm getting:

> [ WARN:0@"a number"] global /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp (239) findDecoder imread_('/abc/d/e/f/g/001.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's because of permissions, but to reveal what is happening exactly best is to run the program with **strace**: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html which will show you the exact problem while it's trying to access to the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

1. Check whether you have permission to read and write the file. You can simply go to directory that contains all subdirectories and give read and write access to all subdirectories to all users.
2. Check whether you can access the directory stored in variable path.
3. Check the spelling of your pathname
4. Use try and catch to open the files - this way you see whether the problem is only one file or all of them which narrows the source of bug down.
5. Check the start of your path. Is that correct and does your program know the path?
6. If you can, download an image and have a look at it. Is it corrupted?

The OpenCV error sounds like certain library paths are not set. Either OpenCV is not properly installed or the path to the library not set. Might be worth to reinstall and set the paths properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check that...

- the path is indeed correct, that is, `/abc/d/e/f/g/001.png` exists
- the process executing the python script has the necessary permissions to read this file
- <strike>the file isn't corrupt (copy it to your local computer and open it in a browser/image viewer)</strike> (After reading [the opencv source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/dad26339a975b49cfb6c7dbe4bd5276c9dcb36e2/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp#L235) that's probably not it)

Comment: Even simpler: try an `os.listdir` to list the content of the directory for verification purposes.

Comment: @ArnabDe , Thanks for your comment. I checked the os.listdir and it shows a list of all the images in the folder g. But when I want to read an image in the folder, the image is an image that all the its elements are zero. May the problem of reading the image be because of the lack of permission in the server?

Comment: @ArnabDe, Additionally, when I want to show that image (zero image) using cv2.imshow I see this error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1268: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'.

Comment: Can you `open()` the file from python? If yes, what do you get when `read()`ing from it? (remember to open the file in binary mode)

Comment: @Sören ,  After reading the opened png image it stored a long variable like this: b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR ...... (to be continued) ..... . What is the problem from? Is there permission for reading these files from the server?

Comment: That's the beginning of a valid PNG file. So there is no permission issue here, you are allowed to read the file. Did you make sure to run that python script the same way (the same user, the same webserver (if applicable), etc.) as your opencv script?

Answer (score 1):

You can also "walk" the filesystem so you get all files below a certain directory:

```
def get_files(path=os.getcwd()):
    files = []
    if not path.endswith(os.sep):
        path += os.sep
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
        for file in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
            files.append(filepath)
    return files
            
files = get_files("/abc/d/e/f")
```

Also, check your file and path. On the linux system's shell (I assume it is Bash):

```
$ ls -l <file> # check if it exists and whether the permissions are correct
$ file <file>  # check the filetype (should hint at being an image)
```